# Find Repeating Intervals of Arbitrary Length of a Series of Categorical Data in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to get the start and end of a **repeating** interval with an **arbitrary length** in `Pandas`? Currently, I'm using a hacky way with `shift()` and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

For example, I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
index   category
0       blue
1       blue
2       blue
3       green
4       green
5       red
6       red
7       red
8       red
9       red
10      blue
11      blue
12      blue
13      blue
14      blue
15      blue
16      green
17      green
18      green
19      green
```

And I want to get this (or at least this information):

```
category    start   end
blue        0       2
green       3       4
red         5       9
blue        10      15
green       16      19
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby((df['category'] != df['category'].shift()).cumsum(), 
            as_index=False)[['category', 'index']]\
  .agg(category=('category','first'),
       first=('index','first'),
       last=('index','last'))
```

Output:

```
  category  first  last
0     blue      0     2
1    green      3     4
2      red      5     9
3     blue     10    15
4    green     16    19
```

Details:

Create a helper series by checking to see if the next value for category is not equal to the current category and using cumsum to create groups in the data.  Aggregate those groups to get first and last index along with the category.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually doing something similar, I just hoped that there might be a more elegant built-in Pandas function (though this is still better looking than what I was doing :) )

Comment: @Zach I don't think so.  You need to use cumsum to keep same values of category in different groups.  Best of luck.  Happy coding.

Comment: Well I appreciate it -- and to you as well!

Answer (score 0):

While the `cumsum` + `agg` solution worked well, it wasn't scaling that well and didn't work with a `DatetimeIndex` so I tested it against a mask approach and got a significant speedup. Posting here for future visitors:

**Cumsum Method**

```
def get_interval_start_end_cumsum(df, col):

    if df.index.name:
        idx = df.index
        df = df.reset_index()
    else:
        idx = df.reset_index().index

    df = df.reset_index().groupby((df[col] != df[col].shift()).cumsum(), as_index = False) \
            .agg(category = (col, 'first'), first = ('index', 'first'), last=('index', 'last')
                ).rename(columns = {'category': col, 'first': 'start', 'last': 'end'})

    for c in ['start', 'end']:
        df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: idx[x])

    return df
```

**Mask Method**

```
def get_interval_start_end_mask(df, col):

    idx_name = df.index.name if df.index.name else 'index'
    mask = (df[col] != df[col].shift()) | (df[col] != df[col].shift(-1))
    df = deepcopy(df[mask].reset_index())

    return pd.concat([
        df.loc[df.index % 2 == 0].reset_index(drop = True).rename(columns = {idx_name: 'start'}),
        df.loc[df.index % 2 != 0].reset_index(drop = True).rename(columns = {idx_name: 'end'}).end
        ], axis = 1)[[col, 'start', 'end']]
```

---

**Results**

*Example `DataFrame` in Question*

```
%timeit get_interval_start_end_cumsum(df, 'colors')
>> 10.8 ms ± 547 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit get_interval_start_end_mask(df, 'colors')
>> 4.84 ms ± 57.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*Real Data w/ 3.5 Million Rows*

```
%timeit get_interval_start_end_cumsum(df, 'a_col')
>> 29.6 s ± 475 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit get_interval_start_end_mask(df, 'a_col')
>> 349 ms ± 9.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As you can see, the mask method scales nicely and when working with large amounts of data it amounts to a ~98.8% improvement in run time.

Hope that helps :)